# How to get current login user's username & email address in C# Azure B2C authentication without Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-b2c

How to get current login username and also their email address? Identity provider for the account is username not email. 
Username is not returned as claims in any of policy such as sign-in, sign-up etc.
Custom attribute like "SpouseName" can be returned as claim for sign in where I can access by `((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("extension_SpouseName").Value`
It's an MVC application.

Comment: Have you checked with the B2C Graph API if the email address is available in the users profile?

Comment: Thank you @ErikOppedijk I can do it through B2C Graph API but I am trying to avoid Graph API in this case.

Comment: And you are sure the "Email Address" claim is not supplied when you at this in your sign in policy? have you checked with JWT.io to see what is in the claim?

Comment: @ErikOppedijk Thank you . It was my bad I haven'd selected email addresses in claims, that's why it was not returning email address. Now I can get the email address with the code `((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("emails").Value`
But still I need to get current username in the Controller.

Comment: Have you looked in the JWT for this? use jwt.io to see what's exactly inside

Comment: @ErikOppedijk Yes, I did. It includes the following sample attributes as claims:
`{
 exp: 1323423423,
 nbf: 1323423423,
 ver: "1.0",
 iss: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/guid/version/",
 sub: "sub guid value",
 aud: "aud guid value",
 nonce: "defaultNonce",
 iat: 1323423423,
 auth_time: 1323423423,
 oid: "oid guid value",
 name: "hello",
 extension_test: "1323423423",
 emails: [
  "a@b.com"
 ],
 tfp: "B2C_1_signin"
}`

Comment: I am surprised why there is no option to select "unique_name" and "upn" as claims in User attributes and  Applications claims in sign-in policy.

Comment: Well, the UPN is kind of strange in B2C, as it is: username/email#EXT@yourb2cdirectory.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: @ErikOppedijk yes, the UPN is kind os strange but I am unable to get UPN as the claims when sign-in or sign-up. do you have any idea how to get it?

Comment: FYI: As of today, if you're using the username login option then a) the username is not available to be passed through in the claims but it can be retrieved via Graph, and b) the email address is available in the claims but can't be retrieved via Graph.   [You might be able to do more if you go with I-believe-still-in-preview Custom policies.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **to select the user attributes** - email address in your signup or signin profile which you are using to validate the access token.[image]

Comment: What is this screen from?  Is it some sort of Azure config screen?